# What's the difference between "неважно" and "ничего"

Tags: словоупотребление, выражения

What's the difference between "**неважно**" and "**ничего**"?
As I understand both mean "**never mind**", but what about usage?
for example when I ask somebody but he/she can't understand me, can I use both of them as the response to interrupt the conversation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Ничего* is not translated to *never mind*, at least in the context you provided.

In your example,

> When I ask somebody but he/she can't understand me

given two choices you reply with *Неважно* if the question was not really important. Alternatives to that can be *Проехали* or *Забудь*.

Let's take a look at another example: someone accidentally steps on your shoes. If the person excuses, you would reply with:

- Never mind.
- No problem.
- That's okay.

In Russian you would reply with:

- Ничего [страшного].
- Все хорошо/в порядке.

Answer (score 9):

Context 1: the difference is not essential.

> - Что ты имел в виду? - **Неважно**.(- Забудь.)
> - What did you mean? - Never mind. (- Forget it.)
> - Что ты имел в виду? - **Ничего**.
> - What did you mean? - Nothing (special).

Context 2: the difference is dramatic (*bad vs OK*).

> - Как ты себя чувствуешь? - **Неважно**. (~ Плохо.)
> - How do you feel? - I don't feel good.
> - Как ты себя чувствуешь? - **Ничего**. (~ Неплохо.)
> - How do you feel? - I'm OK.